# Javascript set Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have a problem. I want to set some attributes with JS.

```
for(i=0;i<div_navi.childNodes.length;i++){                      
    if(div_navi.childNodes[i].nodeName =="SPAN"){
        div_navi.childNodes[i].setAttribute("onclick","getContent(div_navi.childNodes[i].textContent); 
        div_navi.childNodes[i].style.cursor ="pointer";
    }
    if(div_navi.childNodes[i].nodeName =="A")
        div_navi.childNodes[i].setAttribute("href",div_navi.childNodes[i].textContent);
    }
}
```

I want to set a parameter in getContent, but it doesn't work.
Has anybody an idea, how this could work?

Comment: DO NOT use setAttribute to add onclick! There are proper methods to add events. Learn about addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes properly and you should bind event properly and you can set `href` property instead directly.

```
div_navi.childNodes[i].onclick = function(){
    getContent(this.textContent)
};
div_navi.childNodes[i].href = div_navi.childNodes[i].textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set an event with `setAttribute`, you would assign a function to the `onclick` (`div_navi.childNodes[i].onclick = [function]`) property, or better yet:

```
div_navi.childNodes[i].addEventListener('click', getContent);

function getContent(e) {
   console.log(e.target.textContent);
}
```